# issue with debug server proxy config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, signalr

Using the angular 2 debug server, I proxy requests to the real server using `proxy.config.js`. It seems that the `ng2-signalr` library does not respect the proxy configuration, and will attempt requests to whatever was defined as `url` in the `IConnectionOptions` used.

for the following request:

```
GET

localhost:4200/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&user=client&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22compilationhub%22%7D%5D&_=1557816148076
```

the following error is produced:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https
```

What would be the best course of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding the signalr route to `proxy.config.js` and setting the `url` property of my `IConnectionOptions` to `location.origin`. This setup bypasses the default route of `/signalr` so that a double forward slash route is not used.

[image: new proxy config]

[image: with double forward slash route]

[image: without double forward slash route]

[image: working]